# Android Eclipse issue Failed to create BuildConfig class

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am getting "Failed to create BuildConfig class" error while cleaning android project in eclipse.  I have recently installed Eclipse Juno for Mobile developers and while I was trying to import my existing android applications, Eclipse started giving me this kind of error.

Eclipse is working fine If I create new android projects.  What could be the possible cause and probable solution for this issue?

I am using OS - Windows Server 2008

Comment: Previously, I had inexplicable problems like that in Juno- 
And I read somewhere or another that it was a problem with Juno- and if you're developing Android apps, its best to use Indigo. 

But I think you should be able to fix this problem without downgrading your Eclipse. 
I'm searching for an answer to this, myself- 
I'll get back when I can!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the error after updating (installing) Juno and letting it migrate my workspace and local git repo. 
Before that error I got another error:

```
JavaBuilder handling ImageBuilderInternalException while building: <projectname>
```

Finally I found out that the error was caused by file perms and the problem resolved after resetting them:

```
chown <me>:<me> <my-repo>
```

The reason behind the broken permissions: during the process of installing the MOTODEV plugins to Eclipse JUNO I had to start my Eclipse with 'sudo'. Obviously that run overwrote some of my files during the automatic build.

Comment: This is correct - I also had the same problem - and also started eclipse with 'sudo' - I found that gen and bin folders contained files owned by root and not by me. So : sudo rm -rf bin and the same with gen, than refresh and clean project in eclipse. And now it is working.

Comment: how can I fix this on windows7 OS?

Answer (score 0):

This has never happened to me. I tried to import an old workspace in a Juno Eclipse for Mobile and it was ok. I also tried to import only an old android project, and it had no errors. Which ADT version are you using?

I also found an issue related to [9-patch](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22847&can=1&q=BuildConfig&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), maybe it was your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when opening a copy of project that had previously been under source control, and the

`\gen\{com\foo\namespace}\BuildConfig.java` file was read only.

Unchecking the read only flag on the `BuildConfig.java` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Windows 10 and Eclipse. It occurred in the middle of session between two builds. 
I tried restarting Eclipse, tried in vain to change permissions but nothing helped.

I finally rebooted my laptop and problem was gone.