# Failed to create BuildConfig class error message in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i change nothing in google-play-services_lib SDK but i have x on this project and in console 
this error message `"Failed to create BuildConfig class"`

Recently I have not changed anything in google-play-services_lib project or settings or [update Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573810/android-eclipse-issue-failed-to-create-buildconfig-class)

when i try to clean the project i receive problem occurred with those details:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'google-play-services_lib'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\AndroidManifest.xml'.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\AndroidManifest.xml.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\AndroidManifest.xml'.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\AndroidManifest.xml.
```

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Operate eclipse as a manager allowed to eclipse to make changes in  google-play-services_lib files

Solution :

start the eclipse as administrator.
to do so  : 
Close eclipse and then => right click on eclipse Icon => Run as administrator

Comment: Thank you!  My phone died, and I had to get it replaced, and then I started getting this error when I tried to re-install my custom app's.  You saved me from a long, sleepless night of frustration!

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem is just the latest update of the SDK.

Test the following operations on two projects :

- In the project properties (eclipse) -> java build path -> order and export make sure that all your jars in the libs folder are checked.
- And "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties"
- And "Project -> Clean"

I hope you have helped!

Comment: I can not select all the options in the import and export i recieve error... 
the Repair project does nothing, and I can not even clean the project i recieve error

Comment: I need to delete the Google Play SDK and reinstalled, it seems you help?

Comment: try to remove your project, closed eclipse and imported again.

Comment: thank you, Very strange, before I enter and out several times from eclipse and anything not changed .

now I opened eclipse as manager and suddenly there is no x, but problems in projects that use Google Play

I deleted Google Play and reinstalled. now everything works well ...

Comment: Yes really strange! The main is that you found a solution :)