# Eclipse can't delete jar file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm migrating to a new computer and I now have Eclipse et al running on both computers.  At the same time I started getting errors regarding version 5.0.  After researching that problem I was told to install JDK version 8 which I did on both computers.  That problem went away but now I'm getting errors (on both computers) saying that Eclipse could not delete some files. (errors pasted below).

At that point I ran Process Explorer on the jar file and eclipse was the only process that had that handle.  After stopping eclipse I ran PE again and no process had that handle.

It seems either the installation of JDK 8 or the installation of Android 5.0 might have caused this.  Thought I would post here before I remove both of them.
Thanks, Dean

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'google-play-services_lib'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Could not delete 'D:_DBAWorkspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Could not delete: D:_DBAWorkspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Could not delete 'D:_DBAWorkspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Could not delete: D:_DBAWorkspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar.
>   Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'library'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Could not delete 'D:_DBAWorkspace\library\bin\library.jar'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Could not delete: D:_DBAWorkspace\library\bin\library.jar.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Could not delete 'D:_DBAWorkspace\library\bin\library.jar'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Could not delete: D:_DBAWorkspace\library\bin\library.jar.

Comment: Would you mind to try this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/16687349/3502543

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: nothing there worked.  I ended up having to remove the 5.0 libraries.  Must be a bug somewhere.  Once I removed 5.0 everything worked.  Probably more breaking changes.